# SQL запрос - выбрать строки, не содержащие определенного значения

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE lite_db.accounts (
 id_account int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 login varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 date_add date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id_account)
)
```

и таблица

```
CREATE TABLE lite_db.accounts_status (
  account_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  service_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  status tinyint(4) NOT NULL
)
```

Нужно выбирать из таблицы `accounts` некоторые значения, но только для тех строк(аккаунтов), для которых в таблице `accounts_status` не содержится записей с определенным `service_id`.
При этом во второй таблице может быть несколько записей для одного аккаунта, которые отличаются только параметром `service_id`.

Первая мысль - сделать это так:

```
SELECT acc.id_account, acc.email, acc.password, acc.login 
  FROM accounts acc LEFT JOIN accounts_status st ON acc.id_account=st.account_id
  WHERE st.service_id NOT in(1)
  GROUP BY acc.id_account
  LIMIT 10
```

Такой запрос работает правильно(по своей логике), но не дает желаемого результата - он просто выдает все строки, для которых в таблице `accounts_status` содержаться записи с `service_id` отличным от 1.

**Как получать только те записи, для которых в таблице `accounts_status` нет записей с 1 или другим заданным значением `service_id`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT acc.id_account, acc.email, acc.password, acc.login 
  FROM accounts acc 
where acc.id_account NOT IN(
select account_id from accounts_status st
  WHERE st.service_id =1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! А можно ли решить задачу без вложенных SELECT?

Comment: Можно по-разному реализовать разность двух множеств. Например, EXCEPT. Кажется, MySQL этот стандартный оператор не поддерживает.